# Entity Framework doesn't remove rows when updating

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework code first, every time i try to update a record with many to many relation, it is adding new rows and not removing records.

```
public void EditJob(Job job)
{

    Job dbEntry = context.Jobs.Find(job.JobId);

    context.Entry(dbEntry).Collection(j => j.Industries).Load();
    context.Entry(dbEntry).Collection(j => j.SpecialRequirements).Load();
    if (dbEntry != null)
    {
        dbEntry.Industries = job.Industries;
        dbEntry.SpecialRequirements = job.SpecialRequirements;

        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int jobId, JobViewModel model)
{
    Job job = repository.FindJob(jobId);
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        ConfigureEditViewModel(job, model);
        return View(model);
    }
    else
    {
        try
        {
            if (model.SelectedSpecialRequirementsIds != null)
            {
                foreach (int selectedIndustryId in model.SelectedIndustriesIds)
                {
                    job.Industries.Add(repository.Industry(selectedIndustryId));
                }
            }

            if (model.SelectedSpecialRequirementsIds != null)
            {
                foreach (int selectedSpecialRequirementId in model.SelectedSpecialRequirementsIds)
                {
                    job.SpecialRequirements.Add(repository.SpecialRequirement(selectedSpecialRequirementId));
                }
            }

            repository.EditJob(job);

            TempData["success"] = string.Format("Job Edited!");
            return RedirectToAction("List");
        }
        catch
        {
            ConfigureEditViewModel(job, model);
            TempData["fail"] = string.Format("Failed! Might be an connection error, Please try again!");
            return View(model);
        }
    }
}
```

ConfigureEditViewModel contains a multiselect lists

It set selected values of the list with database records, and if I remove a selected value, it doesn't delete, but if i add one that is not in the database yet, it adds a new record and doesn't remove none selected values from the database.

Comment: Cant see any code here that deletes anything from the database. All you seem to be doing is adding (and probably adding duplicates). You would need to first delete all the jobs `Industries` and `SpecialRequirements` then add the selected ones.

Comment: @Stephen For some reason it is not adding duplicates, which is really weird...even if I don't load related entities using .Load(), but that is a good thing. And yes you are right, I figured out that I need to delete all industries and special requirements first, but in my previous projects I didn't have to do that, I just add and entities framework was able to detect any non-selected values from list and delete them if they exists in the database, and I think that was the result of using .Load(), but it is not working this time idk why.